# expected squared prediction error derivation

Tags: probability, expectation

I'm having a hard time deriving the formula on page 223 of Hastie et al. for the expected squared prediction error:

[image: from the book]

Here are my first steps:

$$
Err = E[(Y-\hat f(x))^2] = \\
E[(Y -f(x) +f(x) -\hat f(x))^2 ] = \\
E[(Y -f(x))^2 + 2(Y -f(x))(f(x) -\hat f(x))+(f(x) -\hat f(x))^2]=\\
E[(f(x)+\varepsilon -f(x))^2 + 2(Y -f(x))(f(x) -\hat f(x))+(f(x) -\hat f(x))^2]=\\
E[(f(x)+\varepsilon -f(x))^2] + 2E[(Y -f(x))(f(x) -\hat f(x))]+ E[(f(x) -\hat f(x))^2]=\\
E[\varepsilon^2 -0] + 2E[(Y -f(x))(f(x) -\hat f(x))]+ E[(f(x) -\hat f(x))^2]=\\
\sigma_\varepsilon^2 + 2E[(Y -f(x))(f(x) -\hat f(x))]+ E[(f(x) -\hat f(x))^2]=\\
$$

now I'm stuck, even if I expand the expressions I don't get to the result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conditional on $X=x_0$, we have $Y = f(x_0) + \epsilon$ under the usual assumption that $\epsilon$ and $X$ are independent.

Therefore,
\begin{align}
\mathrm{Err}(x_0) & = E[(f(x_0) + \epsilon-\hat f(x_0))^2]\\
& = E[\epsilon^2] + E[2\epsilon(f(x_0)-\hat f(x_0))] + E[(f(x_0) - \hat f(x_0))^2]\\
& = \sigma_\epsilon^2 + E[(f(x_0) - \hat f(x_0))^2]\\
& = \sigma_\epsilon^2 + E[(f(x_0) - E\hat f(x_0))^2] + E[(E\hat f(x_0) - \hat f(x_0))^2] + 2\times 0\\
& = \sigma_\epsilon^2 + (f(x_0) - E\hat f(x_0))^2 + E[(E\hat f(x_0) - \hat f(x_0))^2]
\end{align}

Comment: thanks. Can you please make the step from line 3 to line 4 more clear?

Comment: Sure. You need just apply $(a-b)^2 = ((a-c) + (c-b))^2 = (a-c)^2 + (c-b)^2 + 2(a-c)(c-b)$ with $a = f(x_0)$, $b = \hat f(x_0)$ and $c = E\hat f(x_0)$.

Comment: I still do not see how $2E[(f(x_0)-E\hat f(x_0))(E\hat f(x_0)-\hat f(x_0)] = 2\cdot 0$, and why is $E[(f(x_0)-E\hat f(x_0))^2] = (f(x_0)-E\hat f(x_0))^2$.

Comment: Among $a = f(x_0)$, $b=\hat f(x_0)$ and $c = E\hat f(x_0)$, only $b$ is random. The other two are constant numbers. Therefore $E[(a-c)(c-b)] = (a-c)(c - E[b]) = (a-c)(c - c) = 0$ by linearity of the expectation. And of course $E[(a-c)^2] = (a-c)^2$ since it is also a nonrandom number.